# WARN PageNotFound:No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a sample mvc project and i got stuck with this issue. When i am calling **/products** url the styles are working fine but when i am trying to call **/products/viewProducts/{productId}** url the styles are not getting added for this call. Here is the captured image while calling the 2nd url
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQCr8.png)

Please help me to find where i am actually doing wrong?
Below are the project details.

Error Detail

```html
WARN  PageNotFound:1147 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/course-project/productsList/viewProduct/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtp3z.png)

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
 version="3.1">
 <display-name>course-project</display-name>

 <!-- Bootstraps the root web application context before servlet initialization -->
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 
 <!-- needed for ContextLoaderListener -->
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
  /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
  /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
  </param-value>
 </context-param>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:src="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/cache.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.pavan.mvc"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>

    </bean>
    
    <mvc:resources  mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/"/>
   <tx:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

HomeController.java

```html
package com.pavan.mvc.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.pavan.mvc.dao.ProductDao;
import com.pavan.mvc.model.Product;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
 
 @Autowired
 private ProductDao productDao;
 
 @RequestMapping("/")
 public String goHome(){
  return "home";
 }
 @RequestMapping("/productsList")
 public String getProducts(Model model){
  List<Product> products = productDao.getAllProduct();
  model.addAttribute("products", products);
  return "productsList" ;
 }
 
 
 @RequestMapping("/form")
 public String getForm(){
  return "form" ;
 }
 
 @RequestMapping("/productsList/viewProduct/{productId}")
 public String viewProduct(@PathVariable Long productId, Model model) throws IOException{
  Product product = productDao.getProductById(productId);
  model.addAttribute(product);
  return "viewProducts";
 }

}
```

productsList.jsp

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp"%>
<div class="container-wrapperr">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
   <h1>All Product</h1>
   <p class="lead">Chechout all the awesome products available now</p>
  </div>

  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
   <thead>
    <tr class="bg-sucess">
     <th>Phto Thumb</th>
     <th>Product Name</th>
     <th>Category</th>
     <th>Condition</th>
     <th>Price</th>
     <th></th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <c:forEach items="${products }" var="product">
    <tr>
     <td><img src="#" alt="image" /></td>
     <td>${product.productName}</td>
     <td>${product.productCategory }</td>
     <td>${product.productCondition }</td>
     <td>${product.productPrice }</td>
     <td><a
      href="<spring:url value="/productsList/viewProduct/${product.productId}"/>">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
     </a></td>
    </tr>
   </c:forEach>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp"%>
```

viewProducts.jsp

```html
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp"%>

<div class="container-wrapperr">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
   <h1>Product Detail</h1>
   <p class="lead">Here is the detail information of the product</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
     <img src="#" alt="image" style = "width: 100% ; height: 100px"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
     <h3>${product.productName}</h3>
     <p>
      <strong>Catogary</strong>: ${product.productCategory}
     </p>
     <p>
      <strong>Condition</strong>: ${product.productCondition}
     </p>
     <p>
      <strong>Product Price</strong>: ${product.productPrice}
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp"%>
```

Comment: do you have bootstrap.min.js inside /course-project/productsList/viewProduct/resources/js/

Comment: It looks like you not included css file properly in your jsp. It should contain contextPath/<css-path>/css-file

Comment: what is location of your js file ? and where it is included in jsp ?

Comment: include your js file in project like this. I am facing same issue and than I googled it and found solution like this :

<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/location of js from resources" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I have all the css and js files in WEB-INF/resources folder

Comment: directly including js include like this :

<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js name" type="text/javascript"></script> 

In your case you have provide resource folder so If you put js in any sub folder inside resources than add it in URL part of script src

Comment: @Darshit  I have css,fonts,js folders inside the resources folder. I have included the above snippet code as it is but still the js files are not getting loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSPs, where are you including bootstrap files? Do you have bootstrap files in your project? If not then add these at the top of your JSPs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

These will include bootstrap lib (and jquery lib) in your JSPs and then it will show your *styles*

@Pavan if you really want not want to write that include stuff in every jsp, then you would have to configure JSPs in your deployment descriptor (your web.xml file) like this:

```
<jsp-config>
<jsp-property-group>
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
<include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jsp/base.jspf</include-prelude>
<trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
</jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Now if you see, I placed this line in the above config `<include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jsp/base.jspf</include-prelude>` 
The  tag in deployment descriptor tells the
container to include the /WEB-INF/jsp/base.jspf file at the beginning of every JSP that belongs in
this property group. This is useful for defining common variables, tag library declarations, or other
resources that should be made available to all JSPs in the group. Similarly, an  tag
defines a file to be included at the end of every JSP in the group. You can use both of these tags more
than once in a single JSP group. You might, for example, create header.jspf and footer.jspf files
to include at the beginning and end, respectively, of every JSP.

Now what will that base.jspf contains? This:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp"%>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp"%>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script
src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
```

But I don't know if you adding bootstrap lines would be picked up by the JSPs or not. But try it. If they don't work then just assume that I never answered this. Sorry. Oh, make sure that this base.jspf is located at `/WEB-INF/jsp/`And then all of your JSP files are also under that path.

Warning: If you do that, you would have to move around your jsps a bit for this to work.

I hope this helps and I hope I have not further confused you or made your work more harder!

Comment: I have bootstrap files in WEB-INF/resources folder

Comment: Thanks this has solved the problem but can't is use the bootstrap and js files which are already there in /WEB-INF/resources folder

Comment: If i delete those files i need to include these links on all the other jsp files as well.

Comment: Sure but where you are adding more stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following url-pattern:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: When i am adding /* i am getting 404 error and this warning

Comment: WARN  PageNotFound:1147 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/course-project/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: remove /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml from <param-value> tag